# Export custom library to importable jar file java

Tags: java, jar, package, executable-jar

I have created a custom package in Java. The directory structure is like this:-

wolpha

```
   /Stream>Stream.java

   /Word/Stream.java

   /Pattern/Stream.java

   /Stream/Stream.java
```

So I just made a non runnable jar file and tried to import the package but it gave a error that the package wolpha does not exist. Tried with a main class with imports included but gave the same error.

How can I add all these classes into a single .jar file such that all classes can be imported into any file. I expect some step-by-step instructions with some down-to-earth language.

Comment: You have to add the `.class` files to the .jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, go to File > Export and follow the instructions as per the screenshots given below:

[image]

[image]